# how to convert a number to signed short in python?

Tags: python

On the arduino -32750-(32760) it produces the result of 26, as it works by default with signed int 16bit.

Let's say I want to get the arduino read interios in a python script via serial and I would like the result of the subtraction -32750-(32760) to be 26 in the python script as well. Is it possible to get the same result in python instead of -65510? Maybe with the Struct library but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

    if __name__ == '__main__':    
    
        a = "-32750"  # value received via serial from the arduino, at a given time.
        b = "32760"   # value received via serial from the arduino, at a given time.
    
        result = int(a) - int(b)        
        print("Result: "+str(result))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the result to 16 bits like this:

```
result = (int(a) - int(b)) & 0xffff
```

I knew the negative side would come up.

```
x16 = (int(a) - int(b)) & 0xffff
result = x16-65536 if x16 & 0x8000 else x16
```

Comment: I tested it with your suggestion, but if I put the values ​​of a = -32760 and b = -32750, in arduino I get = -10 and in python Result: 65526

Comment: The numbers are all nonsense anyway.  You're trying to extract meaning out of overflows.  65526 and -10 have the same bit representation.  I'll show you how to do it, but you really need to think about what you're doing.  GIGO.